# Getting transaction into mempool on BSC quickly

Tags: ether, bsc, txpool

Am trying to gain insights into the details of transaction processing lifecycle on blockchains, in particular on BSC. I understand that once a transaction is in the mempool, the gas price is the main factor under the senders control to ensure inclusion in the next block. Using ethers.js and events via Quicknode, I was able to observe this also empirically by looking at the arrival time of transactions in the mempool ("pending" events) and comparing it to when the transaction became included on the blockchain.

But what is a common (best?) strategy (again from a sender perspective) to ensure that the transaction is included as quickly as possible in the mempool? I don't yet understand the details on how mempools are synchronized, but I noticed that my transactions, after being submitted, are only included after 2 blocks, and never the next block. Thus, I can only assume that my transaction is not quickly enough "spread" accross the mempools.